# Prevent overwriting modules in Julia parallelization

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I've written a Julia module with various functions which I call to analyze data. Several of these functions are dependent on packages, which are included at the start of the file "NeuroTools.jl."

```
module NeuroTools

using MAT, PyPlot, PyCall;

function getHists(channels::Array{Int8,2}...
```

Many of the functions I have are useful to run in parallel, so I wrote a driver script to map functions to different threads using remotecall/fetch. To load the functions on each thread, I launch Julia with the -L option to load my module on each worker.

```
julia -p 16 -L NeuroTools.jl parallelize.jl
```

To bring the loaded functions into scope, the "parallelize.jl" script has the line

```
@everywhere using NeuroTools
```

My parallel function works and executes properly, but each worker thread spits out a bunch of warnings from the modules being overwritten.

```
WARNING: replacing module MAT
WARNING: Method definition read(Union{HDF5.HDF5Dataset, HDF5.HDF5Datatype, HDF5.HDF5Group}, Type{Bool}) in module MAT_HDF5...
(contniues for many lines)
```

Is there a way to load the module differently or change the scope to prevent all these warnings? The documentation does not seem entirely clear on this issue.

Comment: Note that the current Julia parallelization, e.g. with `-p 16`, `@everywhere` etc. is based on separate processes, rather than separate threads.  Multi-threading will start to be introduced in Julia 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally I was looking for the [same thing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/#Base.redirect_stdout) this morning

```
(rd,wr) = redirect_stdout()
```

So you'd need to call

```
remotecall_fetch(worker_id, redirect_stdout)
```

If you want to completely turn it off, this will work

If you want to turn it back on, you could

```
out = STDOUT
(a,b) = redirect_stdout()
#then to turn it back on, do:
redirect_stdout(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the more recent releases, and `@everywhere using ...` is right if you really need the module in scope in all workers.  [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/19073) talks about the problem and has links to some of the other relevant discussions.

If still using older versions of Julia where this was the case, just write `using NeuroTools` in `NeuroTools.jl` after defining the module, instead of executing `@everywhere using NeuroTools`.
The [Parallel Computing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/) section of the Julia documentation for version 0.5 says,

> `using DummyModule` causes the module to be loaded on all processes; however, the module is brought into scope only on the one executing the statement.

Executing `@everywhere using NeuroTools` used to tell *each* processes to load the module on all processes, and the result was a pile of `replacing module` warnings.